# Insert array of variables into mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, web-scraping

So… I have this echo statement:

```
echo 
$results['results'][0]['url'].','
.$results['results'][1]['url'].','
.$results['results'][2]['url'].','
.$results['results'][3]['url'].','
.$results['results'][4]['url'].','
.$results['results'][5]['url'].','
.$results['results'][6]['url'].','
.$results['results'][7]['url'].','
.$results['results'][8]['url'].','
.$results['results'][9]['url'].','

.$results['results'][0]['title'].','
.$results['results'][1]['title'].','
.$results['results'][2]['title'].','
.$results['results'][3]['title'].','
.$results['results'][4]['title'].','
.$results['results'][5]['title'].','
.$results['results'][7]['title'].','
.$results['results'][8]['title'].','
.$results['results'][9]['title'].','

.$results['results'][0]['desc'].','
.$results['results'][1]['desc'].','
.$results['results'][2]['desc'].','
.$results['results'][3]['desc'].','
.$results['results'][4]['desc'].','
.$results['results'][5]['desc'].','
.$results['results'][6]['desc'].','
.$results['results'][7]['desc'].','
.$results['results'][8]['desc'].','
.$results['results'][9]['desc'];
```

That works, and outputs the first 10 url’s, the first 10 titles, and the first 10 descriptions in a google scraper that I have (I’m showing you this to prove that the script works) (there are to many files to show, so I will not show them here). I would like to input the data into a mysql database.

This echo, echos  the values like this: for a certain keyword…

```
    http://cars.mainetoday.com/,http://www.nowvauxhall.co.uk/,http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nDvggf0ltVo,......
```

Like you can see, they are all separated by commas, and ready to input into mysql database. 
The connection and selection of the data base are taken care of by a small script that is working (or I think). (Once again, I am not going to show the files because they are all connected and they are about 5 or 6 of them and they are very long), so…
This is the input code that I’m using to put a row into the table:

```
mysql_query(

"INSERT INTO  'seo'.'serp' (
`keyword` ,
`URL1` ,
`URL2` ,
`URL3` ,
`URL4` ,
`URL5` ,
`URL6` ,
`URL7` ,
`URL8` ,
`URL9` ,
`URL10` ,
`Title1` ,
`Title2` ,
`Title3` ,
`Title4` ,
`Title5` ,
`Title6` ,
`Title7` ,
`Title8` ,
`Title9` ,
`Title10` ,
`Description1` ,
`Description2` ,
`Description3` ,
`Description4` ,
`Description5` ,
`Description6` ,
`Description7` ,
`Description8` ,
`Description9` ,
`Description10`
)
VALUES (
'cars to sale',


".htmlentities($results['results'][0]['url']).",
".htmlentities($results['results'][1]['url']).",
".htmlentities($results['results'][2]['url']).",
".htmlentities($results['results'][3]['url']).",
".htmlentities($results['results'][4]['url']).",
".htmlentities($results['results'][5]['url']).",
".htmlentities($results['results'][6]['url']).",
".htmlentities($results['results'][7]['url']).",
".htmlentities($results['results'][8]['url']).",
".htmlentities($results['results'][9]['url']).",

".htmlentities($results['results'][0]['title']).",
".htmlentities($results['results'][1]['title']).",
".htmlentities($results['results'][2]['title']).",
".htmlentities($results['results'][3]['title']).",
".htmlentities($results['results'][4]['title']).",
".htmlentities($results['results'][5]['title']).",
".htmlentities($results['results'][6]['title']).",
".htmlentities($results['results'][7]['title']).",
".htmlentities($results['results'][8]['title']).",
".htmlentities($results['results'][9]['title']).",

".htmlentities($results['results'][0]['desc']).",
".htmlentities($results['results'][1]['desc']).",
".htmlentities($results['results'][2]['desc']).",
".htmlentities($results['results'][3]['desc']).",
".htmlentities($results['results'][4]['desc']).",
".htmlentities($results['results'][5]['desc']).",
".htmlentities($results['results'][6]['desc']).",
".htmlentities($results['results'][7]['desc']).",
".htmlentities($results['results'][8]['desc']).",
".htmlentities($results['results'][9]['desc']));
```

The input row seems to dislike the table… ;)  I also tried:

```
mysql_query(

"INSERT INTO  'seo'.'serp' (
`keyword` ,
`URL1` ,
`URL2` ,
`URL3` ,
`URL4` ,
`URL5` ,
`URL6` ,
`URL7` ,
`URL8` ,
`URL9` ,
`URL10` ,
`Title1` ,
`Title2` ,
`Title3` ,
`Title4` ,
`Title5` ,
`Title6` ,
`Title7` ,
`Title8` ,
`Title9` ,
`Title10` ,
`Description1` ,
`Description2` ,
`Description3` ,
`Description4` ,
`Description5` ,
`Description6` ,
`Description7` ,
`Description8` ,
`Description9` ,
`Description10`
)
VALUES (
'cars to sale',


".$results['results'][0]['url'].",
".$results['results'][1]['url'].",
".$results['results'][2]['url'].",
".$results['results'][3]['url'].",
".$results['results'][4]['url'].",
".$results['results'][5]['url'].",
".$results['results'][6]['url'].",
".$results['results'][7]['url'].",
".$results['results'][8]['url'].",
".$results['results'][9]['url'].",

".$results['results'][0]['title'].",
".$results['results'][1]['title'].",
".$results['results'][2]['title'].",
".$results['results'][3]['title'].",
".$results['results'][4]['title'].",
".$results['results'][5]['title'].",
".$results['results'][6]['title'].",
".$results['results'][7]['title'].",
".$results['results'][8]['title'].",
".$results['results'][9]['title'].",

".$results['results'][0]['desc'].",
".$results['results'][1]['desc'].",
".$results['results'][2]['desc'].",
".$results['results'][3]['desc'].",
".$results['results'][4]['desc'].",
".$results['results'][5]['desc'].",
".$results['results'][6]['desc'].",
".$results['results'][7]['desc'].",
".$results['results'][8]['desc'].",
".$results['results'][9]['desc']);
```

And still no results… BUT NO ERRORS! ???
If the echo works why can’t I insert the row??? And why does it not show any errors?
I’ve been working on this for about 15 hours! I’m sure it’s very simple...

I've also tried foreach loops, 2 of them, one for each subset of variables. No error, but no rows inserted.

Can anyone help?
Thanks,
Miguel

Like this?

```
mysql_query(

"INSERT INTO  'seo'.'serp' (
`keyword` ,
`URL1` ,
`URL2` ,
`URL3` ,
`URL4` ,
`URL5` ,
`URL6` ,
`URL7` ,
`URL8` ,
`URL9` ,
`URL10` ,
`Title1` ,
`Title2` ,
`Title3` ,
`Title4` ,
`Title5` ,
`Title6` ,
`Title7` ,
`Title8` ,
`Title9` ,
`Title10` ,
`Description1` ,
`Description2` ,
`Description3` ,
`Description4` ,
`Description5` ,
`Description6` ,
`Description7` ,
`Description8` ,
`Description9` ,
`Description10`
)
VALUES (
'cars to sale',



'".htmlentities($results['results'][0]['url'])."',
'".htmlentities($results['results'][1]['url'])."',
'".htmlentities($results['results'][2]['url'])."',
'".htmlentities($results['results'][3]['url'])."',
'".htmlentities($results['results'][4]['url'])."',
'".htmlentities($results['results'][5]['url'])."',
'".htmlentities($results['results'][6]['url'])."',
'".htmlentities($results['results'][7]['url'])."',
'".htmlentities($results['results'][8]['url'])."',
'".htmlentities($results['results'][9]['url'])."',

'".htmlentities($results['results'][0]['title'])."',
'".htmlentities($results['results'][1]['title'])."',
'".htmlentities($results['results'][2]['title'])."',
'".htmlentities($results['results'][3]['title'])."',
'".htmlentities($results['results'][4]['title'])."',
'".htmlentities($results['results'][5]['title'])."',
'".htmlentities($results['results'][6]['title'])."',
'".htmlentities($results['results'][7]['title'])."',
'".htmlentities($results['results'][8]['title'])."',
'".htmlentities($results['results'][9]['title'])."',

'".htmlentities($results['results'][0]['desc'])."',
'".htmlentities($results['results'][1]['desc'])."',
'".htmlentities($results['results'][2]['desc'])."',
'".htmlentities($results['results'][3]['desc'])."',
'".htmlentities($results['results'][4]['desc'])."',
'".htmlentities($results['results'][5]['desc'])."',
'".htmlentities($results['results'][6]['desc'])."',
'".htmlentities($results['results'][7]['desc'])."',
'".htmlentities($results['results'][8]['desc'])."',
'".htmlentities($results['results'][9]['desc'])."')")
```

Not working, no errors...

Ther is the connect file:

```
<?php

$conn_error = 'Could not connect.';

$mysql_host = 'localhost';
$mysql_user = 'root';
$mysql_pass = '';

$mysql_db = 'seo';

if (!mysql_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_pass)||!mysql_select_db($mysql_db)) {

die($conn_error);
}
echo 'connected';
?>
```

Like you see at the echo at the top of the page, it gives "connected" at the end...

Any other sugjestions?

Comment: Beside some more information, that are needed (script), first of all, you should think of normalizing your db. xy1 to xy10 sounds like there is plenty room for better DDL. Putting URL, title and desc in their own table would make that import a lot easier.

Comment: SO I've took another path... something is wrong with the database. I've made a small database and entered the following query and it didn't work. And it is as simple as it gets.                                                                                                                                       "INSERT INTO  `seo`.`serpurl` (
`keyword` ,
`url1` ,
`url2` ,
`url3` ,
`url4` ,
`url5` ,
`url6` ,
`url7` ,
`url8` ,
`url9` ,
`url10`
)
VALUES (
'bicicletas',  'te',  'te',  'te',  'te',  'te',  'te',  'tet',  'et',  'ttttttet',  'e'
);"

Answer (score 0):

You have to enclose the text data in `'` like this

```
'".htmlentities($results['results'][0]['url'])."',
^                                               ^
```

Others as well

Comment: I've just done that... no result. I've added the connect file (it sowing at the end of the first comment). I've also tried what Sammy sugested. No result. Im sure that the answer is simple. do you need all the files?

Comment: Ok. So it's done... After a massive quantity of attempts it's done. I do not know what I did wrong but that doesn't matter. Thanks for your answers. Miguel